# How easy is it to convert AMP-HTML to MIP-HTML?

Tags: mobile, amp-html

All the [documentation for MIP](https://www.mipengine.org/) pages seems to be in Chinese so really not sure how it works, however some sources claim it is basically a clone of AMP.

Has anyone got any experience of converting a full AMP build into MIP pages? Is it a case of swapping out like for like code or is it more of a complete rebuild?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was forked from AMP a long time ago, and has specific components that cater to the China market (e.g. mip-appdl, a component for downloading apps, and supports multiple Android app store download sources).

If you are mostly using basic components and extensions, you might be able to get pretty far by just regex replacing "amp-" with "mip-" and the AMP runtime with "https://c.mipcdn.com/static/v1/mip.js".

Comment: Thanks Michael, roughly as I thought but good to have it confirmed!